# Different approach to sockets in Java

Tags: java, sockets, servlets

I am trying to write a socket application that needs to be able to distribute people connected as clients to people connected as operators, and operators should be able to respond any client.

I have a few approaches in my mind, but i'm not sure if they will work or not and the example codes i looked up are a bit superficial so the questions in my mind are;

1. First I'm wondering if i write a server side application and transfer input and output addresses of clients to operators, will the operators be able make the connection directly, or do i have to send messages over server?
2. Will it be bad practice for a server side application to listen sockets/open ports?
3. What other approaches would you suggest for such a program(Operator side has to be a multi platform desktop application)

Comment: @Oren Yosifon The operator side has to be a desktop application, but since there has to be multiple operators and multiple clients, i thought i have to write a server side app as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you will be using addresses, that can be a problem, as the clients may be connected behind firewalls, and client addresses may also change.
2. it is not a bad practice, in fact, this is what servers do, they listen to ports.
3. I would suggest not to try and write an implementation based on raw sockets. There are several very good frameworks that can help you with efficient, resilient two-way client-server messaging you can leverage:

   - One possibility is to use Websockets. Websockets have very good server side implementation in Java(See [Spring Websockets](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html) ), and you can also consume and communicate with the server via web sockets from a java application via javax.websocket API.
   - If you need the messaging platform to have features like durability, you can use an architecture which will use [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com) is a messaging middleware, and have clients and servers communicate through RabbitMQ. this will probably be easiest to implement.
   - If you need very fast communication that would scale to millions of endpoints, you should take a look at [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org).

with all three options, there are very good examples of several messaging paradigms, like RPC, publish-subscribe, multicast etc.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't do that, as then you will need to hand UPnP and STUN on your clients
2. What do you think Tomcat does? It listens on a port...

Honestly, I'd say just put up a WebSocket-capable web server; all clients (clients+operators) connect there, and the server handles message passing / routing of messages.